# How to duplicate base object in an overlay with kustomize?

Tags: kustomize

I have a base object (custom resource) that I need multiple times with a different name and one property added (or changed). So I have defined a base yaml file and referenced it in the overlay `kustomization.yaml`.

```
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
|   └── base.ClusterOutput.yaml
└── my-env
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

Now I need to update the `metadata.name` field and add a property which can be done with patches in `kustomization.yaml`

```yaml
patches:
  - patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/opensearch/logstash_prefix
        value: <new-value>
      - op: replace
        path: /metadata/name
        value: <new-name>
```

Until here it works as expected, but in some environments I need more than the one instance of the custom resource and I can't figure out, how to do that. I tried multiple patches, but they override each other and I end up with one object having the last patch.
I don't want to write multiple base objects, in some environments I need only one and they are equal apart from the name and the one property anyway.
Is there some way I can do this with kustomize?